# Is there a way to convert earth location geocentric to tangent coordinates at some particular location?

Tags: coordinates, astropy

I'm using astropy for some simulations. I have a set of EarthLocations that I want to convert to an XYZ coordinate system pointing to some sky coordinate. It's a very simple coordinate rotation.

I have some code that is close to working (See below). xyz is the geocentric coordinates derived from EarthLocation.geocentric. ha is ra - local sidereal time, and dec is the declination of the source. ra and dec come from a SkyCoord. I'd prefer to do this with EarthLocations and SkyCoords. The output coordinates should be tangent to the earth and have one axis pointing towards a SkyCoord.

```py
def xyz_to_uvw(xyz, ha, dec):
    """
    Rotate :math:`(x,y,z)` positions in earth coordinates to
    :math:`(u,v,w)` coordinates relative to astronomical source
    position :math:`(ha, dec)`. Can be used for both antenna positions
    as well as for baselines.

    Hour angle and declination can be given as single values or arrays
    of the same length. Angles can be given as radians or astropy
    quantities with a valid conversion.

    :param xyz: :math:`(x,y,z)` co-ordinates of antennas in array
    :param ha: hour angle of phase tracking centre (:math:`ha = ra - lst`)
    :param dec: declination of phase tracking centre.
    """

    x, y, z = numpy.hsplit(xyz, 3)

    # Two rotations:
    #  1. by 'ha' along the z axis
    #  2. by '90-dec' along the u axis
    u = x * numpy.cos(ha) - y * numpy.sin(ha)
    v0 = x * numpy.sin(ha) + y * numpy.cos(ha)
    w = z * numpy.sin(dec) - v0 * numpy.cos(dec)
    v = z * numpy.cos(dec) + v0 * numpy.sin(dec)

    return numpy.hstack([v0, v, w])
```

I think that the output should be a set of EarthLocations referred to a particular frame.

I've studied the documentation but cannot see how to do this.

Comment: There may not be a solution yet, but there is an open issue: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/7766